# Multiple instances of class with different parameters based on configuration file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, configuration

So I have a simple configuration class `PubsubSettings`:

```cs
public class PubSubSettings
{
  public string ProjectId { get; set; }
  public string TopicId { get; set; }
  public int PartnerId { get; set; }
  public string SubscriptionId { get; set; }
}
```

I have previously only had one of these configured in my appsettings.json but now I want to be able to handle an arbitrary number of them.

I have another class, `PubSub`, that I usually inject an `IOptions<PubSubSettings>` into. And this, in turn, gets injected into my `Worker` class.

```cs
services.Configure<PubSubSettings>(configuration.GetSection(nameof(PubSubSettings)));
...
services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
```

So, what I want to do now, is add a new `Worker` as a hosted service for each entry in my AppSettings `PubSubSettings` section and inject the relevant `IOptions<PubSubSettings>` into each of these (along with the standard `ILogger`).

So in essence, I'd like this config block:

```json
 "PubsubSettings": [
    {
      "ProjectId": "project1",
      "TopicId": "topic",
      "PartnerId": 1,
      "SubscriptionId": "sub1"
    },
    {
      "ProjectId": "project2",
      "TopicId": "topic2",
      "PartnerId": 2,
      "SubscriptionId": "sub2"
    }    
  ]
```

To end up with two hosted services being created, one with the first set of options and the other with the second.

I've seen a few questions looking for similar things but nothing I could find quite lined up with this so I'm a bit stumped. Any ideas?

The solution is Dotnet 5.

Comment: Just call AddHostedService multiple times with specifying concrete settings you want to use. All IHostedService interfaces will be invoked before your app fully starts.

Comment: Yeah, that defeats the point of pulling this from the config file doesn't it? Unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean

Comment: I meant run a loop for config entries, like *foreach(var ps in config.pses)* OR if you want it to be unit tested through DI, create IHostedService, which aggregates all of them and do the same thing. I would do the second one, because I love managing things myself, but for simplicity the first one approach is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from what I've been able to find, there's no way to do this out-of-the box.

However, This can be done manually using a combination of `ActivatorUtilities` and `Configuration.Bind()`.

```cs
private void CreateWorkers(IServiceCollection services, IConfigurationRoot configuration)
{
    List<PubSubSettings> pubsubSettings = new();
    configuration.Bind(nameof(PubSubSettings), pubsubSettings);
    
    foreach (PubSubSettings setting in pubsubSettings)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IHostedService>(s => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<Worker>(s, ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<PubSub.PubSub>(s, setting)));
    }
}
```

Essentially, you can use `Bind` to get the configuration objects from the JSON. Then you can manually construct the `Worker` for the call to `AddHostedService` using `CreateInstance`.

Two calls are needed in this case, one to generate the `PubSub` for the worker (in which we pass the setting parameter) and the other to generate the `Worker` itself.

`ActivatorUtilities` essentially injects everything you need for the object except the parameters you've provided.

We need to use `.AddSingleton<IHostedService>` because of the way that the [framework checks for dupes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68007164/4700841) with `AddHostedService()`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try creating a class only for the object and let the PubSubSettings class only for the array:

```
public class PubSubSettings
{
  public PubSubObject[] PubSubs { get; set; }
}

public class PubSubObject
{
  public string ProjectId { get; set; }
  public string TopicId { get; set; }
  public int PartnerId { get; set; }
  public string SubscriptionId { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the startup class you should use `Bind` to get the current value of the array to create a `Worker` for each `PubSub`:

```
PubSubSettings settings = new PubSubSettings();
Configuration.GetSection(nameof(PubSubSettings)).Bind(settings);
...
foreach(PubSubObject item in settings.PubSubs)
{
   services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
}
```

Then in the `PubSub` class you need to search the `PartnerId` inside the Array.

Or you could follow the approach described in the section **Named options support using IConfigureNamedOptions** in the Microsoft docs: [Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Not a bad answer, but I think I've  found something that more closely requires what I need, thanks anyway though

Comment: @Persistence Then post the solution.

Comment: I have done... https://stackoverflow.com/a/68006700/4700841

Comment: That being said... I'm not 100% sure it has worked afterall so I might end up deleting it