# Calling AddHostedServices multiple times doesn't create multiple instances

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

[So I thought I'd solved my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68006700/4700841) (with some help from a colleague).

Essentially, I was trying to create two instances of a class, as hosted services, each with different parameters.

However, it seems that, whilst there are two calls to `AddHostedService`, only one instance is actually instantiated.

What's going on here?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/38751

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you need the same hosted service started twice?

Comment: @Steven - Same service, different injected parameters

Comment: Can you update your question to reflect this?

Comment: @Steven - Fair point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is intentional behavior as documented here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/38751

As you can see from the [source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/01b7e73cd378145264a7cb7a09365b41ed42b240/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/src/ServiceCollectionHostedServiceExtensions.cs#L22), the hosted service will be registered as a singleton via a call to TryAddEnumerable.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddHostedService<[DynamicallyAccessedMembers(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicConstructors)] THostedService>(this IServiceCollection services)
    where THostedService : class, IHostedService
{
    services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IHostedService, THostedService>());

    return services;
}
```

The [TryAddEnumerable](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/01b7e73cd378145264a7cb7a09365b41ed42b240/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/src/Extensions/ServiceCollectionDescriptorExtensions.cs#L591) method will iterate all current services and compare both the `ServiceType` and implementor type.  If it determines that the registration already exists, it will not add an additional registration.

Comment: Note that you can add it as a singleton multiple times... just the default `AddHostedService` doesn't do it, but you can use `AddSingleton` (instead of `TryAdd`) and it'll add the same `IHostedService` multiple times just fine

Comment: Great point, I'll explicitly call that out.

Comment: Okay, so I've tried this, but now the `StartAsync` method of the `Worker:BackgroundWorker` doesn't get called. How do I get a reference to this singleton so I can call it manually?

Comment: Call it from where? What are you trying to solve for? Your question was specifically _why_ doesn’t this work and the answer is by design. If you have a separate question on what you are trying to accomplish, that probably should be answered separately.

Comment: It's fine, I've sorted it, had to use `services.AddSingleton<IHostedService>` thanks for pointing me to the source